# how to get the count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have tried a lot to figure how to get the count from two tables with respect to master table

I have three tables

[image]

Using these table values I need to get this output..

[image]

Tried but could get the desired result
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)
  [SQL - LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281967/sql-left-outer-join-and-where-clause)
  http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/combination-of-left-outer-join-and-where-clause-383248.html

Comment: tried left outer join, right outer join, inner join, ...

Comment: I am trying the given solution, please give me a moment to mark the correct answer and vote up.. what make you guys to downgrade?

Comment: @AnandMohanAwasthi: There are many users that post a question without showing what they tried. many of them have not tried anything at all. I'm not saying that this is the case with you but if you don't show what you did, we can't be sure (and some will assume you just want others to do the job for you).

Comment: @ypercube: I was bit busy in trying the provided solution, check my profile you can easily figure that this is my third question . I want to say that before writing or asking question i do lot reseach, anyways I think I have found the solution..

Comment: @ypercube: And hats off your solution.. you are genius..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first `GROUP BY` in subqueries, then `JOIN` to the main table:

```
SELECT
    a.AttributeId     
  , COALECSE(cntE, 0) AS cntE
  , COALECSE(cntM, 0) AS cntM
FROM
    AttributeMaster AS a
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT
          AttributeId
        , COUNT(*) AS cntE
      FROM 
          EmployeeMaster 
      GROUP BY
          AttributeId
    ) em
      ON  em.AttributeId = a.AttributeId
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT
          AttributeId
        , COUNT(*) AS cntM
      FROM 
          MonthlyDerivedMaster 
      GROUP BY
          AttributeId
    ) mdm
      ON mdm.AttributeId = a.AttributeId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AttributeId,
(SELECT COUNT(Eid) FROM EmployeeMaster WHERE AttributeMaster.AttributeId = EmployeeMaster.AttributeId) as master_eid,
(SELECT COUNT(Eid) FROM MonthnlyDerivedMaster WHERE AttributeMaster.AttributeId = MonthnlyDerivedMaster.AttributeId) as monthly_eid
FROM AttributeMaster
```